# how can I store image and retrieve the same in sqlite-android

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I am developing an application that stores some static images in sqlite and I want to retrieve the same in a imageview. 
how do I do this
thanks.

Comment: store image on sdcard ,use path of sdcard and store it in database. And later on when ever you required image just use this path to retrieved image and shown it in image view.

Comment: I want to store the image in database as blob. I dont want to use file path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sqlite3 supports the `blob` type, you can save the bitmap content using the `blob` type.

However, the `blob` type has a size limit, and to save to a blob type is difficult.

So, I suggest to save the bitmap local or on the sdcard, and save the path in the database.

**added** :

table define a column with name 'image' using `blob` type

```
    Bitmap map = ...;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bufferStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16*1024);
    map.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bufferStream);
    byte[] bytes = bufferStream.toByteArray();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("image", bytes);
```

convert the image byte array, using **SQLiteDatabase** class method or content provider as you like:

`public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)`

to insert to table, so it save the image to `blob`.

**and then:** when you query the `blob` data, you can create the image like this:

```
        BitmapFactory.Options option2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        option2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        // added for reducing the memory
        option2.inDither = false;
        option2.inPurgeable = true;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, option2);
```

hope it can implement your request. -):

Comment: I want the exact image to be stored and not the path. I know i need to use blob. But I am not getting how to implement it.

Comment: awesome, works perfectly, thanks! about storing the image on the SD card: the user might move/delete it.. while some devices may not have a SD card to begin with.